# Using maps inside class and accessing values via get() and set() functions from other class

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am unable to use add values this map defined in header file as protected attribute from class member function.

```
class xyz{

protected:

    map < string, string > *tagsMap;


public:
    xyz();

    //set Tags
    void addTag(string _tagName, string _tagValue) const;
}


// In cpp class, 

//set new Tags
void xyz::addTag(string _tagName, string _tagValue) const {

    //map < string, string > tagsMap ;
    //gives error until I uncomment above line, but thats local map

    tagsMap.insert(pair<string, string>(_tagName, _tagValue));

    // first insert function version (single parameter):
    tagsMap .insert(pair<string, string>(_tagName, _tagValue));

    for (auto& t : tagsMap )
        cout << "addTag():" << t.first << "=" << t.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to a map?

Comment: i dont need a pointer.. i just want to save new values to the map on every function call and later access them...

Comment: also add `;` after your class def

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 problems:

**1) Class member is declared a pointer**
The commented line  inside `addTag()`:

```
// map < string, string > tagsMap;
```

It is **not** a pointer, which is the reason why it works if you uncomment the local map declaration.

However, this is not correct logically since it's not a member of your class - it shadows your `tagsMap` class member.

Thus, you need to declare `tagsMap` in your `xyz` class a **non**-pointer.

```
map < string, string > *tagsMap;
                   //  ^ remove asterisk '*'
```

**2) Missing Semicolon after class definition**

Add `;` semicolon, after your class definition

```
class xyz {
   ...
}
// ^^^ add semicolon here
```

**3) Const function**
Remove `const` in `addTag()` to be able to write on `tagsMap` class member

```
void xyz::addTag(string _tagName, string _tagValue) const { .. }
                                                 // ^^^^^ remove const
void addTag(string _tagName, string _tagValue) const;
                                            // ^^^^^ remove const
```

Comment: And if you do need to use a pointer for some reason, you need to use '->' to call member functions rather than just '.'

Answer (score 2):

Yes pointer was not needed.
It worked after making the function non-const as suggested by @codekaizer in comments above.

```
class xyz{

protected:
map < string, string > tagsMap;

public:
xyz();

//set Tags
void addTag(string _tagName, string _tagValue);
}
```

// In cpp class,

```
void xyz::addTag(string _tagName, string _tagValue) {
 tagsMap.insert(pair<string, string>(_tagName, _tagValue));
}
```